# What rule in CSS will guide me in understanding which div class to use to style the h1 and p tags?

Tags: html, css

So I want to style the `h1` and `p` elements without affecting the `p` elements inside the `.container` div inside of the `.main` div.

```
<div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Cats are from Mars and Dogs are from Venus</h1>
        <p>Which planet do you prefer to go visit?</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="display-exercise.html">display</a></li>
          <li><a href="float-exercise.html">float</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.4.3_the_position_property/icon.png" alt="cat image">
        <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
        <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions
          to challenging problems.</p>
        <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most
          challenging projects.</p>
        <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I do intuitively get that I would have to add the h1 and p text styles in the `.header` selector, but I am not sure how to explain why.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.4.3_the_position_property/outerspace_landscape.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;*/
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

Does this have to do with inheritance?

Comment: Use **CSS Selector Reference** See this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Or you can create a classes and pass to your `h1` and `p` tags.

Comment: You can easily put a  `span` with a class around all the `h1` and `p` tags you want to style.

Comment: So in this case I did ```.header h1```, would it make a difference had I done ```.container h1``` instead? Or better yet, is there a rule that would govern which of the two being that ```.container``` is inside of ```.header```? Or, does it not make a difference?

Comment: If you did `.container h1` every element that is inside of that container that has an `h1` will be inherited. However, if you did `.header h1` every element of `h1` inside of the `.header` class will only be inherited.

Comment: @Jorden1337, seems so simple, but I had to check in. Could you paste your response as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more about [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than inheritance.

With my rules below, each one gets more specific.

```css
h1 {color:#F00;}
.container h1 {color: #0F0;}
.header .container h1 {color:#00F;}
```

```html
<h1>"Naked" H1</h1>
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Cats are from Mars and Dogs are from Venus</h1>
    <p>Which planet do you prefer to go visit?</p>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="display-exercise.html">display</a></li>
      <li><a href="float-exercise.html">float</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>H1 Out of the header</h1>
    <img src="https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.4.3_the_position_property/icon.png" alt="cat image">
    <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
    <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions to challenging problems.</p>
    <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most challenging projects.</p>
    <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the explanation you were looking for. However, I altered your code into a very simple example. I'm targeting all `h1` that are inside the `.container` to have a color of green. and all `h1` that are inside the `.header` to have a color of red. It's a fundamental part of CSS specificity.

```css
.header h1 {
  color:red;
}

.container h1 {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h1>Cats are from Mars and Dogs are from Venus</h1>
      <div class="container">
      <h1>This is a header not being inherited with color red. It's outside of the container</h1>
        <p>Which planet do you prefer to go visit?</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
      <h1>This is a header not being inherited with color red. It's outside of the container</h1>
      </h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="display-exercise.html">display</a></li>
          <li><a href="float-exercise.html">float</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
      <h1>This is header not being inherited by the color red. It's outside of the container</h1>
      </h1>
        <img src="https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.4.3_the_position_property/icon.png" alt="cat image">
        <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
        <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions
          to challenging problems.</p>
        <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most
          challenging projects.</p>
        <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Only problem with this is if `h1` is also in `<div class="header"><div class="container">.....</div></div>` E.g: https://jsfiddle.net/6sr4g2t3/

Comment: thanks, @JonP, you captured the answer I was looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

may be simply give #id or .class to the lemenets you want to style 
something like this :

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="Cat_from_mars">Cats are from Mars and Dogs are from Venus</h1>
    <p id="planet_you_prefer">Which planet do you prefer to go visit?</p>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then add your css
if i understand you correctly